# Stay in the bottom of the page. Rails, Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I hava a form (form_remote_tag) that updates a comments section.

The form is in the bottom.

I would like to keep the page scrolled to the bottom so the text box is always visible.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it.

```
<%form_remote_tag ... :complete => "window.scroll(0,100000);" do %>
```